# Regular Expression Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm attempting one of the beginner coderByte challenges, Simple Symbols.  Challenge summary below.

"Using the JavaScript language, have the function `SimpleSymbols(str)` take the `str` parameter being passed and determine if it is an acceptable sequence by either returning the string true or false. The str parameter will be composed of `+` and `=` symbols with several letters between them (ie. `++d+===+c++==a`) and for the string to be true each letter must be surrounded by a `+` symbol. So the string to the left would be false. The string will not be empty and will have at least one letter."

```
function SimpleSymbols(str){
  var RegExp = /\+\w\+/gi;
  var regexp1 = /^\w/gi;
  var regexp2 = /\w$/g;

  if(regexp1.test(str) == true){
    return false
  } else if(regexp2.test(str) == true){
    return false
  } else if(RegExp == true){
    return true
  }                       

}

console.log(SimpleSymbols('+d+=3=+s+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols('f++d+'));
```

The first regular expression I'm testing, `/^\w/gi`, comes back `undefined`, and I can't figure out why?
https://regex101.com/ is a great tool I've used before, and my expression does identify `f` as the first character in the string, but when I test it in codepen, it comes back `undefined` in the console.

Comment: What `else if(RegExp == true)` supposed to do? `RegExp` is not a good variable name BTW.

Comment: A hint: `if(regexp1.test(str) == true)` could be replaced with `if(regexp1.test(str))`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just combine these regular expressions such that you use `if(/^\w|\w$/g.test(str))`?

Comment: Its returning `undefined` because none of your regular expression pass the test, in which case none of your `true`/`false` get returned, but just the end of the expression, which automatically returns `undefined`.

Comment: When you say `for the string to be true each letter must be surrounded by a + symbol` can you specify whether or not the `+` can be shared between letters? Is `+a+b+` valid or would the correct way of writing it be `+a++b+`?

Comment: *for the string to be true **each letter** must be surrounded by a + symbol* - Instead of looking for the "success" case, you should be looking for the _failure_ case. After all, finding one or more matches for `+x+` doesn't really tell you anything. There could still be a mismatch somewhere. What are the failure cases? There are two: a non-plus followed by a letter, or a letter followed by a non-plus. If you search the string and find either of those conditions, then you have the failure case. If neither of those conditions matches, you have success. How could you test for those two cases?

Comment: @MichaelGeary on the contrary, he should be looking for valid cases and consider anything that doesn't match those valid cases to be invalid.

Comment: @ctwheels Clearly there are many ways to solve this. The approach I described can easily be implemented in a single regular expression test, in fact what I wrote is a literal description of the regular expression needed. (I didn't want to give OP the answer but just drop a hint.) I did miss one thing though - when I said "non-plus", that could either be a character that is not a plus sign, or the beginning or end of the string. So that complicates the RE just a bit, but it still is just a single test.

Comment: @ctwheels Also your point about `+a+b+` vs. `+a++b+` is an excellent one. This is the kind of issue that many of these coding challenges fall down on - they don't really give a complete specification and an adequate number of test cases.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I agree there are multiple ways of solving this. I guess my last comment is more opinion based, but the OP *knows* what makes a string valid. The OP didn't really specify what makes it explicitly *invalid*, thus the OP should find positive matches. Failing to have supplied us with all the information needed to assist, however, I don't think we can properly help the OP find an appropriate solution. As such I'm marking to close this question since it's lacking information.

Comment: @ctwheels Hopefully this discussion will inspire OP in a couple of ways: First, to make sure the specification is clearly understood, that any gray areas like the one you mentioned are clarified, and that there are enough test cases to verify the code. And second, to try more than one approach. When I've done coding exercises like this for learning purposes, I've always found it valuable to explore alternate ways of solving the problem and not just stop when I find the first one that works.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's response, I take that as long as the letter is between two '+' characters, then it is valid.  i.e. @ctwheels, either +a++b+ or +a+b+ is valid.

I do plan on going back through.  As flawed as code challenges maybe in clarity, they provide scenarios for beginners like myself to practice and explore areas where I am weak in... which is pretty much the entire language.

Keep the comments coming.

Comment: @RyanSpeight I've added an answer to your question. I hope this solves your question. It works according to all the information you've presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/05o0Gc/1)

```
^[+=\d]*\+(?:[a-z]\+[+=\d]*)+$
```

Alternatively, using the opposite logic (catching invalid strings instead of valid ones), you can use `(?:^|[^+])[a-z]|[a-z](?:[^+]|$)`

#### Usage

Please note the valid/invalid strings below have been created according to the OP's explanation of *valid* and *invalid* strings: That `each letter must be surrounded by a + symbol.` and that the plus sign `+` may be shared between characters such that `+a+a+` is valid (specified in comments below the question).

```js
var a = [
  // valid
  "++d+===+c++==+a++",
  "+a+a+a+",
  "+a++a+",
  "+a+",
  // invalid
  "++d+===+c++==a",
  "+=d+",
  "+dd+",
  "+d=+",
  "+d+d",
  "d+d+"
];
var r = /^[+=\d]*\+(?:[a-z]\+[+=\d]*)+$/mi;

a.forEach(function(s){
 console.log(r.test(s));
});
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[+=\d]*` Match any number of characters in the set (`+`, `=`, or digit)
- `\+` Match a literal plus sign `+`
- `(?:[a-z]\+[+=\d]*)+` Match one or more of the following

  - `[a-z]` Match a lowercase ASCII letter
  - `\+` Match a literal plus sign `+`
  - `[+=\d]*` Match any number of characters in the set (`+`, `=`, or digit)
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Interesting - the version of the negative match that I was experimenting with when we were commenting is almost identical to yours (great minds think alike?): `/(^|[^+])[a-z]|[a-z]([^+]|$)/i.test(s)`. The only difference is that I didn't use the non-capturing `?:`. I think it should be OK without the `?:`, but now I wonder if I missed some case by leaving it out?

Comment: Same here! `"+d+==+c++==+a+".match(/(?:^|[^+])[a-z]|[a-z](?:$|[^+])/i)` hence upvoted

Answer (score 0):

It's returning undefined because your expression does not meet any of the criteria. Since you have no else {} defined, than nothing gets returned. Thus you get undefined. Try this:

```js
function SimpleSymbols(str){
  var RegExp = /\+\w\+/gi;
  var regexp1 = /^\w/gi;
  var regexp2 = /\w$/g;

  if(regexp1.test(str) == true){
    return false
  } else if(regexp2.test(str) == true){
    return false
  } else if(RegExp == true){
    return true
  } else {
    return "catch all here";
  }

}

console.log(SimpleSymbols('+d+=3=+s+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols('f++d+'));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the comment, but I know that var RegExp should return true.  When I first ran the .test(str) by itself, it returned both strings as true.  So, I'm unsure as to why it doesn't recognize the RegExp now.

Comment: Because you aren't testing the expression. The first two have .test() while RegExp doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single regex and the string.test() method (*which returns just true/false*).

Below are 2 different ways (regex) to do it .

First requires a separate `+` between word chars. Example  `+a++b+`  (true)

```
 ^ 
 (?: [+=]* \+ \w \+ [+=]* )+
 $
```

Second can take a common `+` between word chars. Example  `+a+b+` (true)

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      [+=]* \+ \w 
      (?= \+ )
 )+
 [+=]* 
 $
```

```js
var patt1 = new RegExp("^(?:[+=]*\\+\\w\\+[+=]*)+$");
function SimpleSymbols_1(str){
   return patt1.test(str);
}

var patt2 = new RegExp("^(?:[+=]*\\+\\w(?=\\+))+[+=]*$");
function SimpleSymbols_2(str){
   return patt2.test(str);
}

console.log(SimpleSymbols_1('+d+=3=+s+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols_1('f++d+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols_1('+a+b+c+'));

console.log(SimpleSymbols_2('+a+b+c+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols_2('+a+=+c+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols_2('+a++c+'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for throwing some support/comments my way.  Again, I am new to JavaScript and Regular Expressions are fairly foreign to me, though I am gaining some traction in understanding them.  Here is the updated solution I posted.  It's quite convoluted and perhaps a more inelegant and non-simple way to come to the right answer, but it worked.

```
function SimpleSymbols(str){
  var RegExp = /\+[a-z]\+/gi;
  var regexp1 = /^[a-z]/gi;
  var regexp2 = /[a-z]$/g;
  var regexp3 = /[a-z]\=/gi;
  var regexp4 = /\=[a-z]/gi;

  if(regexp1.test(str) === true){
    return false
  } else if(regexp2.test(str) === true){
    return false
  } else if(regexp3.test(str) === true){
    return false
  } else if(regexp4.test(str) === true){
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }                      
}

console.log(SimpleSymbols('+d+=3=+s+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols('f++d+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols('+d===+a+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols('+a='));
console.log(SimpleSymbols('2+a+a+'));
console.log(SimpleSymbols('==a+'));
```

I was sure there had to be a way to use only one regular expression, but again, I'm still very much a novice.

Thanks again everyone.